# C# initializing list

Tags: c#, list

Where can I initialize List to let other functions know that it exists so Visual Studio doesn't show any errors. For the time being it looks like this:

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

  public class BazaDanych
    {

   public class Album
   {
       public int IDNumber { get; set; }
       public string AlbumName { get; set; }
       public string Artist { get; set; }
       public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
       public int TrackAmount { get; set; }
       public string Location { get; set; }
       public int Rating { get; set; }

       public Album(int _id, string _name, string _artist, int _releasedate, int _trackamount, string _location, int _rating)
       {
           IDNumber = _id;
           AlbumName = _name;
           Artist = _artist;
           ReleaseDate = _releasedate;
           TrackAmount = _trackamount;
           Location = _location;
           Rating = _rating;
       }
   }

   static int currid = 1;
   public void addnew()
   {
       int ID = currid;
       if (ID == 1);
       List<Album> AlbumsList = new List<Album>();
    //useless for this question
   }

   public void printlist()
   {
       foreach ( int i in AlbumsList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(i);
       }
   }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new BazaDanych();
        //useless  
        db.addnew();
        db.addnew();



    }

}
```

}
Visual Studio screams that AlbumsList doesn't exist in print function.

Comment: Pass it as an argument

Comment: Make it a property...?

Comment: You should present a *minimal* example here. If your code snippet contains code that is explicitly "useless" for the question, why not remove it?

Comment: Also, what do you think `if (ID == 1);` does?

Comment: ^Note: remove the semicolon (@ OP)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring AlbymsList inside the addnew() method. This means it is only visible within that method. You need to declare it outside any method.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a class member/property:

```
public class BazaDanych
{
   private List<Album> AlbumsList = new List<Album>();
   ....
}
```

Comment: When I initialize it as private it says I need an object reference to use it in function call in main.

Answer (score 0):

First off, move the class definition of `Album` outside of the class `BazaDanych`, idealy make a separate class file for it but this would work too

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   public class Album
   {
     //Album logic
   }

  public class BazaDanych
    {
    //Baza logic
    }
}
```

Second, as Amiros states, move the definition out of the `addNew` method into the class (`BazaDanych`) and use this reference within `AddNew`

```
public class BazaDanych
{
    private List<Album> AlbumsList = new List<Album>();
    public void AddNew()
    {
        AlbumsList.Add(new Album(...));
    }
}
```